# Errors with Google Custom Search popular queries

Tags: javascript, json, google-custom-search

I've got a custom search on a website and I'd like to display the most popular searches using the Custom Search Popular Queries option. First off, the code Google gives in the process is wrong - I kept getting bad requests. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453212/google-custom-search-popular-queries-bad-request-error) helped me rebuild the correct URL, but now I'm getting a syntax error.

When I run the test, I get, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in the console from the JSON information that comes back.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="queries"></div>
        <script src="https://cse.google.com/query_renderer.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/cse/api/USERID/cse/CSEID/queries/js?view=overall&callback=(new+PopularQueryRenderer(document.getElementById('queries'))).render"></script>
```

The colon throwing the error is after `title`, but I can't figure out why that would be happening.

```
{
"title" : "MTBoS Search Engine",
"popularQueries" : [ ...rest of the results array... ]
}
```

Lastly, I tried calling the JSON response from a [formatting checker](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) by copying and pasting the call URL and it returned with a handful of HTML errors. Could it be an issue with the query renderer script?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the example on Google (you should be able to see it at the bottom of your *Google Custom Search/Statistics and Logs* page), you should see that instead of single quotes, Google’s example uses encoded double-quotes:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/cse/api/USERID/cse/CSEID/queries/js?view=overall&callback=(new+PopularQueryRenderer(document.getElementById(%22queries%22))).render"></script>
```

I do not understand why single quotes do not work there, however, I have verified that for me at least they do not. If I put single quotes there, I get the error you saw:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.

If I put percent-encoded quotes there, it successfully creates the list of popular queries.

It appears to be the single quotes that are the issue, not that they aren’t encoded for use in URLs. If I replace %22 with %27 (encoded single quotes), the same “Unexpected token” error results.

If there is a reason you wish to avoid the percent-encoding, it is [legal to use single quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) to surround attributes, so you could do this:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/cse/api/USERID/cse/CSEID/queries/js?view=overall&callback=(new+PopularQueryRenderer(document.getElementById("queries"))).render'></script>
```

According to the HTML specs, double quotes are legal inside of single quotes, and I’ve verified that this also works on my search page.

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong because I thought I'd tried every combination of single and double quotes that can be tried. Working now. Much appreciated.